# D3 js line chart shows dot on mouse over and mouse out

Tags: d3.js

In d3 js I follow line chart zoom-able graph link jsfiddle.net/KSAbK/1/ in this line graph I want to shows dot visible like [this](http://codepen.io/jayarjo/pen/gzfyj). how should I do this?

After updating code dot are visible but when I scrolled graph dot was fixed at given positions, below is my zoomed function

```
function zoomed() {
console.log(d3.event.translate);
console.log(d3.event.scale);
svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
svg.select(".x.grid")
    .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));
svg.select(".y.grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));
svg.select(".line")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("class","dot")
 .attr("height",7)
 .attr("width",7)
 .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
 .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add circles where you have data points. The circles could be small, and grow or change its color on mouse over. You can add circles to your chart with

```
// Append circles to the chart
var circles = chartBody.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr('r', 10)
    .attr('fill', 'blue');
```

Draw the points after drawing the path, so they are not hidden by the line. Regards,

Comment: Hi, It shows dot in circle but when scroll in out that circle position   was remain fixed? How that circle move as per scroll up or down?

Comment: Hi I was added same code in zoomed functions but it still not work :(

Comment: Update your question adding the relevant code, it will be easier for the community to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing it with animation, then first remove old circles using

```
d3.selectAll(".dot").remove();
```

OR

```
 svg.selectAll(".dot").remove();
```

And redraw it as per your requirement, so your code will be probably as below.

```
function zoomed(zoomlevel) {
console.log(d3.event.translate);
console.log(d3.event.scale);
svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
svg.select(".x.grid")
    .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));
svg.select(".y.grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));
svg.select(".line")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

svg.selectAll(".dot").remove();

svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr('r', zoomlevel*10)  //zoomlevel can be -2,-1,1,2... except zero
    .attr('fill', 'blue');

}
```